# How to implement obstacle avoidance in Netlogo using the concept of two intersecting lines ( turtle heading vs wall made of patches)

Tags: netlogo

How can we convert the heading, of a Netlogo turtle, into a line equation (y = mx + c ) so that it can be compared to another line equation (eg that of patches representing a wall) ?

I need to convert the heading of a turtle into a line equation. Then compare the heading line equation with the line equation of a wall (which will have either a fixed x or a fixed y – depending on whether the wall is vertical or horizontal) 
There is an interception lines example code in the library (that I don’t understand that well) which is using moving segments. I think what I am after is a bit simpler. Perhaps a better starting point would be the code below that I found in one of the forums.

`to-report calculate-line [ x y angle]
 let m tan angle
 let A m
 let B -1
 let C ( - m * x + y )
 report (list A B C)
 end`

What must be done in order to 'read' the x and y values of the current turtle's heading and input those into the equations?  Similarly, how can a set of patches that have been coloured to represent a wall, can be converted into a line equation that will be used to check possible intersection (between the heading line equation and wall line equation) ? 
For example I have create a line/segment of grey patches using the below code to represent the wall
and given it is straight, there must be a way to convert this into a line equation (which will have
a fixed y value - so that I will only have to 'test' the x value against the line equation of the turtle's heading. (In the simulated environment there are 4 walls in total - 2 vertical and 2 horizontal)

`ask patches with [abs pycor = 10] [set pcolor grey]
 ask patches with [abs pycor = 11] [set pcolor grey]`

Answer (score 2):

The `x` and `y` in the arguments of `calculate-line` refer to the current position of the turtle, and `angle` the angle between the turtle's current heading and the x axis, measured counter-clockwise with zero "east".  I have no idea why the `B` is there, it is simply set and returned as -1, so a simpler version would be

```
to-report calculate-line [x y angle]
  let m tan angle  ; the slope
  let c y - m * x   ; the constant
  report (list m c)
end
```

and it would be called by a turtle. However, NetLogo measures a turtle's `heading` clockwise from the vertical axis, with zero "north", so we need to adjust the heading before taking its angle. The easiest way of doing this is to add 90 degrees to the heading, rotating everything clockwise, and, since that would make a turtle traveling (say) NE travel SE, thus reversing the sign of the slope, we need to take the negative of the result. Finally, if we let the turtle itself determine the line, it can simply fill in its own location and heading.

We then end up with

```
to-report calculate-line
  ; We need to remember that NetLogo measures 
  ; heading from the vertical axis, while the
  ; tan function assumes an angle measured from
  ; the horizontal axis. Thus we rotate the
  ; heading 90 degrees before taking the tan.
  ; also we deal separately with headings of 
  ; 0 and 180, where the slope is "infinite",
  ; and headings of 90 and 270, where the slope
  ; is zero.
  let m 0
  (ifelse (heading mod 180 = 0) [set m 10e16] ; m is "infinite"
  (heading mod 90 = 0) [set m 0]
  [set m (- tan (heading + 90))])
  let c ycor - m * xcor
  report (list m c)
end

ask one-of turtles [show calculate-line]
```

This way, the turtle fills in its own coordinates and heading. Note that we treat headings along the axes as special cases, and make and "infinite" (vertical) slope a very large number.

If you have four walls, you will need to be careful to test that the line does not intersect one wall beyond the limits of one perpendicular to it.  Also, if you are using the pxcor and pycor of the wall to define its position, remember that the intersections will occur in the middle of the wall, i.e., the middle of the patch.

Comment: Thank you very much! The calculate-line makes much more sense now. The next challenge is to create a line equation out of the walls that are available. The walls (forming a squared area) do have fixed coordinates but have ‘gaps’ vertically or horizontally representing doors or a passage. I must find a way to have an equation for each portion of the walls and every time compare the calculate-line heading with that of the wall in order to check intersection. I am assuming that all the line equations must be put into some list or set. Correct?  ( I am very new to Netlogo)

Comment: Or perhaps I should create turtles that will have characteristics of a wall, because if I use patches, I will have to use pxcor, etc for the line equation, instead of xcor - which is one I would need most likely, when comparing the two lines for the point of intersection.  Not sure what is right approach to this puzzle.

Comment: would it be enough to know at which wall the path intersects and at what coordinate?  (Presumably you would know if there ware a door at that coordinate.)

Comment: indeed, that is what I am trying to achieve - while a turtle is moving, it will come across an obstacle, a wall in this case and will have to change direction. So if I can calculate the intersection point, I can ask the turtle to change direction before 'hitting' the wall. Based on your example I wrote this :  to-report wall-line
   let m 90
   let c ( 10 - m * pxcor )
   report ( list c pxcor )  -  aiming to have the coordinates of the line created by the wall (which has a fixed pycor = 10). But I think there is something wrong with my selection of the m value.

Comment: If the wall has a fixed `pycor`, then it is a horizontal line and thus has a slope of zero.  Its equation would simply be `y = 10 + 0 * x`, or `y = 10`. Similarly, a vertical wall at x = 10 would have an "infinite" slope and the equation `x = 10`.  `m` is the slope of the wall, not its heading.

Comment: Thank you very much Professor! (I should revisit my trigonometry school books). What I am 'worried' about, is even if I manage to compare the two lines for an intersection point, it will never be accurate given the integers vs decimals situation. Turtle’s coordinates have decimals, but patches’ coordinates are always integers. Furthermore, a turtle/agent can be positioned at any point within its patch; it doesn’t have to be in the center of the patch  (based on the manual) One idea I had is to make the wall with turtles, rather than patches ( then I can compare apples to apples)

Comment: But will have to figure out how to do that (I guess I should be creating turtles with same size as patches and force them to stay still at all times during the simulation run - no fd should do the trick...)

Comment: All numbers are real (decimal) numbers in NetLogo. Some, like patch coordinates, just take on integer values.There is no integer arithmetic in NetLogo. Calculations involving integer values are still evaluated as real numbers (e.g., 3 / 2 = 1.5), as of course are calculations involving both decimal and integer values.  Moreover, if say a wall is at pxcor = 11, you can specify that the equation of the left edge is x = 10.5 and that of the right edge is x = 11.5.

Comment: Now turtles too have a size and shape, so if you want a collision to be between the edge of a turtle and the edge of a wall, it becomes a bit more complicated, depending on the shape of the turtle.