# Can walls (with the use of patches) be represented by line segments in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

In Netlogo we can represent walls, by creating a number of patches in one line with a specific color. Is there are a way to create line segments representing each wall? What are the options? Creating a list of some sort?  Or maybe patches should not be used to serve as walls in this case?

The incentive being, if we have the line segment of the wall / boundaries that can be represented by a line equation, we can compare that line with the line created from the direction a turtle is heading - so that if there is a point where the two lines cross each other, that point can be referred to and used in a bouncing procedure for example.

Comment: You might look at a similar question which was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646674/how-to-implement-obstacle-avoidance-in-netlogo-using-the-concept-of-two-intersec