# Which primitive should be used when comparing coordinates in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am still learning Netlogo and not sure how to go on about comparing the coordinates from a heading against a fixed set of coordinates in a data set.  'One-of' primitive does not seem to be the right tool for the job nor is 'member?', as I am not getting the intended result.

```
   let wallcoor []
   set wallcoor [ [-17 11] [-16 11] [-15 -11] [-14 11] [-13 11] [-12 11] [-11 11] [-10 11] [-9 11] [-8 
                  11] [ 0 11 ] [ 1 11 ] [ 2 11 ] [ 3 11 ] [ 4 11 ] [ 5 11 ] [ 6 11 ] [ 7 11 ] [ 8 11 ] 
                  [12 11] [13 11 ] [14 11] [15 11] [16 11] [17 11] ]  
   let heading-equ calculate-line (xcor) (ycor) (heading-to-angle heading)
   ifelse ( heading-equ = one-of wallcoor )
        [ bk 0.5 lt random 30 rt random 30 fd 1 ]
        [ rt random 30 lt random 30 fd 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is `member?`.  If you want to know if a given item exists in a list, then `member? item wallcoor` will return true if item is in `wallcoor`, and false if it is not.

But, I fear that you are comparing apples and oranges here.  It seems from your code that `heading-equ` is giving you the equation of line describing the path of a turtle at a given location with a given heading, but you are comparing that to a list of points describing a wall.  I would think that you would instead look to see where the equation for the path intersects with the equation for the wall to see where the turtle will hit the wall.  Moreover, what if the turtle hits the wall between -17 11 and -16, 11?  The location of the turtle is not always in the center of a patch.  Of course I may have completely misinterpreted what `heading-equ` is.

A question similar to this is at [How to implement obstacle avoidance in Netlogo using the concept of two intersecting lines ( turtle heading vs wall made of patches)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646674/how-to-implement-obstacle-avoidance-in-netlogo-using-the-concept-of-two-intersec).  You might check that out.

Just to elaborate on the intersecting line approach, your wall has the equation `y = 11`  If you have an equation for the path of the turtle, then you can figure out where those two lines intersect by solving them simultaneously.  Then you can look to see if that point of intersection lies between (say) `x > -9.5 and x < -0.5` to see if the intersection is in that doorway. (I've put the door between the edges of patches -10 11 and 0 11.)  You also need to see if the intersection is outside the boundaries of the world (`x < -17.5 or x > 17.5`).  If so the turtle will hit the side of the world before it hits the wall.

There is another whole approach to this that involves the turtle looking ahead for an obstacle.  In the Models Library you will find two nice examples under Code Examples, "Look Ahead Example" and "Wall Following Example".

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. You have understood correctly and your fear is correct (my naivety level shows – eg: did not take into account location of turtle not being in the centre of patch always). I had a look at the link however, although well explained, I am not sure how to adapt it for this issue. How can I turn this fixed x and y coordinates into a line equation?(so that I will end up with apples to apples comparison). Bare, in mind that the wall has ‘gaps’ of various patch lengths representing doors or just passages.

Comment: I've updated my answer to (I hope) address your question.  Charles

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. I guess I need to revise a bit my geometry  and try to make sense of it again.

Comment: Indeed the 2 examples are nice. I used their approaches before.  However, the line equation approach is an act of last resort. I have used all combination of patch-etc / colour and distance / in-cone / in-radius approaches for my obstacle avoidance procedure. Whilst all work beautifully when used alone, I get at least one or two agents going through walls when the object avoidance procedure is run together with other procedures, such as run to nearest exit, flocking, avoid shooter. The agents must run to nearest exit whilst avoid walls, gunman,etc. Maybe I am asking too much from my agents.